# Mongoose Schema.pre insertMany middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose with nodeJs and I'm trying to implement a middleware called when using insertMany .
In mongoose documentation there are no example at all, but they confirm that insertMany model function
triggers the following middleware: insertMany().

I have a basic User schema and I need insertMany hooks to hash password with bcrypt:

```
UserSchema.pre('insertMany', async function (err, docs, next) {

  try{
    docs.map(async function (doc, index) {
      // async hash password
      doc.password = await User.hashPassword(doc.password);
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  next();
});
```

I'm not posting all schema because all the rest works, including password hashing and 'save' hooks.
I cannot understand why I am getting this error when I try to insert many users:

**next is not a function**

Usually I call next() to proceed to next middleware, but in this case it doesn't work.
If I remove next(), code won't go on to next middleware and in both cases users are not inserted.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you provide wrong arguments in callback. Hook apply only 'next' argument. You need change your callback function arguments from (err, docs, next) to (next, docs) and it should work for you.

Details you can see here
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please, where have you found the arguments? In mongoose docs the order is next as second parameters, not the first.

Comment: in link that i sent , you can see that they are using next as first param

Comment: in that link, as in the rest of the documentation, there are no example about insertMany hook at all.  Anyhow, your suggestion works :) Thanks!

Comment: as of mongoose 5.10.8, I had to do (docs, next) in order to make it work: (next, docs) was wrong.